# Android SQLite Repeated Elements

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an issue with SQLite on android.  Right now, I'm pulling a JSON object from a server, parsing it, and putting each sub-object in a Table with things such as the Name, Row_ID, unique ID, etc.  using this code:

```
public void fillTable(Object[] detailedList){
    for(int i=0;i<detailedList.length;++i){
        Log.w("MyApp", "Creating Entry: " + Integer.toString(i));
        String[] article = (String[]) detailedList[i];
        createEntry(article[0], article[1], article[2], article[3], article[4], article[5]);
    }
}
```

createEntry does what it sounds like.  It takes 6 strings, and uses cv.put to make an entry.  No problems.

When I try to order them however, via:

```
public String[] getAllTitles(int m){
    Log.w("MyApp", "getTitle1");
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_URLID, KEY_URL, KEY_TITLE, KEY_TIME, KEY_TAGS, KEY_STATE};
    Log.w("MyApp", "getTitle2");
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLENAME, columns, null, null, null, null, KEY_TIME);
    Log.w("MyApp", "getTitle3");

    String title[] = new String[m];
    Log.w("MyApp", "getTitle4");

    int i = 0;
    int rowTitle = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TITLE);
    Log.w("MyApp", "getTitle5");

    for(c.moveToFirst();i<m;c.moveToNext()){
        title[i++] = c.getString(rowTitle);
        Log.w("MyApp", "getTitle " + Integer.toString(i));
    }

    return title;
}
```

Each entry actually has many duplicates.  I'm assuming as many duplicates as times I have synced.  Is there any way to manually call the onUpgrade method, which drops the table and creates a new one, or a better way to clear out duplicates?

Secondary question, is there any way to order by reverse?  I'm ordering by time now, and the oldest added entries are first (smallest number).  Is there a reverse to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want duplicates in one column then create that column with the `UNIQUE` keyword. Your database will then check that you don't insert duplicates and you can even specify what should happen in that case. I guess this would be good for you:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    theone TEXT UNIQUE ON CONFLICT REPLACE
)
```

If you insert something into that table that already exists it will delete the row that already has that item and inserts your new row then. That also means that the replaced row gets a new `_id` (because `_id` is set to automatically grow - you must not insert that id yourself or it will not work)

Your second question: you can specify the direction of the order of if you append `ASC` (ascending) or `DESC` (descending). You want `DESC` probably.

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLENAME, columns, null, null, null, null, KEY_TIME + " DESC");
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had seen the "desc" tag before, but it was for people implementing other SQL classes than I am.  Thanks!